# Tracking for subdomain with google

Tags: html

I have a small website sitting in a sub-domain of my main site. I'm trying to track it but no matter what I do and where I place this code for google analytics I can't get it to successfully start tracking (or even collecting) the data.

So is there something I have to do specially for tracking this sub-domain of mine? What might it be?

I have this, but it's not working. :/ Does it take a couple hours to let you know you did it right or if I do it right it lets me know (and then I come back in a day to see some of the tracked info?)

This is what I have just before the  tag right now..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-30225564-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mysite.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this post? http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#multipleDomains

Looks like you just need to set the `_setDomainName` to your subdomain name.

Another reference: http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2011/01/google_analytics_subdomain_tracking.php

Modify your google analyitics code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-30225564-4']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mysite.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'mysite.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

The line `_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'mysite.com']);` tells google to ignore anything with just mysite.com in it so your sub domain should be good.  I got that from the 2nd article above under point 3 if you need more information.

Comment: Whew! Thanks it's working! I'll be sure to look through those articles in more depth. Been kind of busy getting this last minute festival website up. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Is there a way to ask for it not to track particular ip addresses? As I go in there a lot to make changes and always have the window open. I don't want it to necessarily track me.

Comment: within google analytics admin there is a filter option. you can add IP address exclusions.  Here you go: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481